# iOS how is the Swift Playground app recording the screen?

Tags: ios, swift-playground

If you look at video at 3:00 mark:

https://youtu.be/sI6w3-iSBSk?t=3m

the app allows you to record the screen. I am curious how recording the screen can be implemented and if there are any limitations to this?

I am not talking about using the Quicktime on mac to record iphone screen, I am referring to record video of screen within an app.

Comment: Looks like they're using ReplayKit

Comment: @dan You should post that as an answer.